# Ionic Framework: IonHeader / IonTitle sub title without line seperator

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic Framework (using it with React) and I'm trying to create a new mobile app as practice. I'm trying to create the following:

[image]

When scrolling I want the big "Discover" text to become as a header for the page. So here is my code:

```
<IonPage>
      <IonHeader mode="ios" translucent>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonButton fill="clear">
            <IonIcon slot="start" icon={menu} />
          </IonButton>
          <IonTitle>Tab 1</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>

      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <IonHeader mode="ios" collapse="condense">
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonTitle size="large" className="mainTitle">{t('Home.Title')}</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>

        <IonList>
        </IonList>
      </IonContent>
</IonPage>
```

And the result looks like the following:

[image]

What I don't understand is if, and how I can put my sub-title below the title (and space it - which I assume I would do with CSS)? And how can I remove the line separating the title from the content (the gray line that goes across the page)?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the class name `"ion-no-border"` in the `<IonHeader>`

Something like that:

`<IonHeader className="ion-no-border">`

I hope it be useful for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).